# Cannot declare a public protocol extension with internal requirements

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-protocols, swift-extensions

I am programming a media player app and created my own framework for managing all the player functionality. In this framework I have a public protocol called `PlayerControllerType` and an internal protocol `_PlayerControllerType`. In `PlayerControllerType` I have declared all the methods and properties, which should be accessible from outside the framework. In `_PlayerControllerType` I have defined a couple of properties, which are used by the concrete types implementing `PlayerControllerType` inside the framework. One of these types is `PlayerController`. Its declaration is as follows:

```
public class PlayerController<Item: Equatable>: NSObject, PlayerControllerType, 
_PlayerControllerType, QueueDelegate
```

Now I want to provide a couple of default implementations for the classes in my framework, which conform to `PlayerControllerType` and the internal `_PlayerControllerType`, for example:

```
import Foundation  
import MediaPlayer  

public extension PlayerControllerType where Self: _PlayerControllerType, Item == MPMediaItem, Self.QueueT == Queue<Item>, Self: QueueDelegate {  

    public func setQueue(query query: MPMediaQuery) {  
        queue.items = query.items ?? []  
    }  

}
```

This works as expected in Xcode 7 Beta 4. Yesterday I updated to Beta 6 and got this error:
"Extensions cannot be declared public because its generic requirement uses an internal type" (also see screenshot).
[image: The error in Xcode]

I find this error irritating. Of course no type outside of my framework benefits of this extension because it cannot access the internal protocol `_PlayerControllerType`, but it is very useful for the types inside my framework which implement both `PlayerControllerType` and `_PlayerControllerType`.

Is this just a bug in the Swift compiler or is this the intended behavior?
It's is pretty unfortunate that this doesn't work anymore because now I have to put these methods into a newly created base class for all my PlayerControllers.

Any help or feedback would greatly appreciated.

Kai

EDIT:
Here is a shortened example of the protocols and their extensions:

```
public protocol PlayerControllerType {
    typealias Item
    var nowPlayingItem: Item {get}
    func play()
}

protocol _PlayerControllerType {
    var nowPlayingItem: Item {get set}
}

public extension PlayerControllerType where Self: _PlayerControllerType {

    /* 
    I want to provide a default implementation of play() for
    all my PlayerControllers in my framework (there is more than one).
    This method needs to be declared public, because it implements a
    requirement of the public protocol PlayerControllerType. 
    But it cannot be implemented here, because this extension 
    has the requirement _PlayerControllerType. It needs this requirement,
    because otherwise it cannot set the nowPlayingItem. I don't want to
    expose the setter of nowPlayingItem.
    I could make a base class for all PlayerControllers, but then I'm
    restricted to this base class because Swift does not support
    multiple inheritance.
    */
    public func play() {
        if nowPlayingItem == nil {
            nowPlayingItem = queue.first
        }
        // Other stuff
    }

}
```

Comment: It could be helpful if you post a (minimal) *self-contained* example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Why does your extension need to be public?

Comment: I added an example to better explain why the extension needs to be public

Comment: @KaiEngelhardt did you solve this? Kind of funny, I am also writing a player actually and I want to have some methods in a protocol public and some methods internal. Is it possible?

Comment: This seems to be a [long lasting bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-4695) of Swift.  
Maybe there are some updates to this problem I couldn't find

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare an access level of the `_PlayerControllerType` protocol as '**public**'.

```
public protocol _PlayerControllerType {
   // some code
}
```

According to ([The Swift Programming Language - Access Control](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html)),

> A **public** members cannot be defined as having an internal or private type, because the type might not be available everywhere that the
>   public variable is used. Classes are declared as internal by default,
>   so you have to add the public keyword to make them public.
>
> A member (class/protocol/function/variable) cannot have a higher
>   access level than its parameter types and return type, because the
>   function could be used in situations where its constituent types are
>   not available to the surrounding code.